# Метод Хаффмана. Помогите найти и исправить ошибку

Tags: c++

Есть метод Хаффмана, но при выполнение в кодировании где-то добавляються переносы строк и из-за этого происходит неправильная кодировка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
    int number; //число
    char symbol; //символ
    Node *left, *right;

    Node()
    {
        left=right=NULL;
    }

    Node(Node *L, Node *R)
    {
        left =  L;
        right = R;
        number = L->number + R->number;
    }
};

//перегрузка параметров l, r
struct MyCompare
{
    bool operator()(const Node* l, const Node* r) const
    {
        // возвращаем True, если параметр l < r
        return l->number < r->number;
    }
};

vector<bool> code;
map<char,vector<bool> > table;

void BuildTable(Node *root)
{
    if (root->left!=NULL)
    {
        code.push_back(0);
        BuildTable(root->left);
    }

    if (root->right!=NULL)
    {
        code.push_back(1);
        BuildTable(root->right);
    }
    //если нашли букву (если буква существует)
    if (root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
        table[root->symbol]=code; //ассоциируем эту букву с кодом

    code.pop_back();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    if(argc != 4)
    {
        cout << "\n         -----------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "        |             Лабораторная работа №2            |" << endl;
        cout << "        |         Сжатие данных: метод Хаффмана         |" << endl;
        cout << "         -----------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << " ---------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "| Инструкция:                                                   |" << endl;
        cout << "|                                                               |" << endl;
        cout << "|\t [lab2] +                                               |" << endl;
        cout << "|                                                               |" << endl;
        cout << "|\t [входной_файл.расширение] +                            |" << endl;
        cout << "|\t [кодируемый_файл.расширение] +                         |" << endl;
        cout << "|\t [декодируемый_файл.расширение]                         |" << endl;
        cout << "|                                                               |" << endl;
        cout << " ---------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // считаем частоты символов
        ifstream ifile(argv[1], ios::out | ios::binary);
        map<char,int> m;
        while (1)
        {
            int c = ifile.get();
            if (c == -1)
                break;
            m[(char)c]++;
        }

        //while (!f.eof())
        //{ char c = f.get();
        //   m[c]++;}

        // записываем начальные узлы в список list
        list<Node*> t;
        for( map<char,int>::iterator itr=m.begin(); itr!=m.end(); ++itr)
        {
            Node *p = new Node;
            p->symbol = itr->first;
            p->number = itr->second;
            t.push_back(p);
        }

        //  создаем дерево
        while (t.size()!=1)
        {
            t.sort(MyCompare());               //сортируем list
            Node *SonL = t.front();            //берем первый элемент и присваем первому элементу который идет в списке
            t.pop_front();                     //удаляем первый элемент, на его место становиться второй
            Node *SonR = t.front();            //который стал дальше первым - становиться правым сыном
            t.pop_front();

            Node *parent = new Node(SonL,SonR);
            t.push_back(parent);
        }

        Node *root = t.front();   //root - указатель на вершину дерева
        // создаем пары 'символ-код':
        BuildTable(root);
        ifile.clear(); ifile.seekg(0); // перемещаем указатель снова в начало файла

        ofstream ofile(argv[2], ios::out | ios::binary);
        int count=0;
        char buf=0;

        while (!ifile.eof())
        {
            char c = ifile.get();
            vector<bool> x = table[c];
            for(int n=0; n < x.size(); n++)
            {
                buf = buf | x[n]<<(7-count);
                count++;
                if (count==8)
                {
                    count=0;
                    ofile << buf;
                    buf=0;
                }
            }
        }

        ifile.close();
        ofile.close();

        cout << "Сжатие выполнено..." << endl;

        ifstream iifile(argv[2], ios::in | ios::binary);
        ofstream oofile(argv[3]);

        Node *p = root;
        count = 0;
        char byte;
        byte = iifile.get();
        while(!iifile.eof())
        {
            bool b = byte & (1 << (7-count) ) ;
            if (b)
                p=p->right;
            else
                p=p->left;
            if (p->left==NULL && p->right==NULL)
            {
                oofile << p->symbol;
                p = root;
            }
            count++;
            if (count == 8)
            {
                count = 0;
                byte = iifile.get();
            }
        }
        iifile.close();
        oofile.close();
        cout << "Файл разархивировано..." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Текст кодируемого файла:
qwqwqwqwqwqwqqqqqqqqqq \n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\тут заканчиваться переносы строки.
Раскодирует строку по тексту правильно до добавляет больше в 2 раза переносов. Ну и отображается конечно это все на размерах:
1.txt - кодируемый файл
2.huf - закодированый
3.txt - декодированый
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарна, есть кто поможет решить проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в Windows работаете?

Думаю, проблема в этом:

```
ifstream iifile(argv[2], ios::in | ios::binary);  // Бинарный
ofstream oofile(argv[3]);                         // Текстовый
```

Текстовый файл при записи `\n` записывает как `\r\n`.

Comment: Да, Windows.
Спасибо. Немного помогло. Изображения, допустим, теперь нормально кодируются, а вот текстовые файлы в размерах все равно недочет где-то.